# Why is this TSQL sub-query slowing this query

Tags: performance, t-sql, subquery

I have a query, which I need to speed up:

```
    SELECT
Distinct Refs.SpecialtyReferredTo
FROM ABI_RiO.dbo.vwSGReferrals Refs
LEFT JOIN ABI_RiO.dbo.vwSGAppointmentsPD Apps ON Refs.ClientID = Apps. ClientID AND Refs.ReferralNumber = Apps.ReferralNumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN ABI_RiO.SchemaSG.AmsOutcome AS AOUT ON AOUT.Code=APPs.Outcome
LEFT JOIN ABI_RiO.SchemaSG.ClientIndex CI ON Refs.ClientID = CI.ClientID
LEFT JOIN ABI_RiO.SchemaSG.GenGPPractice GP ON GP.Code = CI.AIMTCCurrentGPPractice
where Refs.DischargeReason IS NULL
AND ((Apps.ContactID = ISNULL((SELECT Max(Apps2.ContactID)
FROM ABI_RiO.dbo.vwSGReferrals Refs2
LEFT JOIN ABI_RiO.dbo.vwSGAppointmentsPD Apps2 ON Refs2.ClientID = Apps2. ClientID AND Refs2.ReferralNumber = Apps2.ReferralNumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN ABI_RiO.SchemaSG.AmsOutcome AS AOUT ON AOUT.Code=APPs2.Outcome
WHERE Refs2.ClientID = Refs.ClientID
AND Refs2.ReferralNumber = Refs.ReferralNumber
AND NationalCode=5),
(SELECT Max(Apps2.ContactID)
FROM ABI_RiO.dbo.vwSGReferrals Refs2
LEFT JOIN ABI_RiO.dbo.vwSGAppointmentsPD Apps2 ON Refs2.ClientID = Apps2. ClientID AND Refs2.ReferralNumber = Apps2.ReferralNumber
WHERE Refs2.ClientID = Refs.ClientID
AND Refs2.ReferralNumber = Refs.ReferralNumber
))) OR Apps.ContactID IS NULL)
GROUP BY GP.Code, Refs.SpecialtyReferredTo
```

This takes forever to execute. However, if I split off the last part of the query the code executes in a few seconds. i.e.

```
     SELECT
Distinct GP.Code, Refs.SpecialtyReferredTo
FROM ABI_RiO.dbo.vwSGReferrals Refs
LEFT JOIN ABI_RiO.dbo.vwSGAppointmentsPD Apps ON Refs.ClientID = Apps. ClientID AND Refs.ReferralNumber = Apps.ReferralNumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN ABI_RiO.SchemaSG.AmsOutcome AS AOUT ON AOUT.Code=APPs.Outcome
LEFT JOIN ABI_RiO.SchemaSG.ClientIndex CI ON Refs.ClientID = CI.ClientID
LEFT JOIN ABI_RiO.SchemaSG.GenGPPractice GP ON GP.Code = CI.AIMTCCurrentGPPractice
where Refs.DischargeReason IS NULL
AND ((Apps.ContactID = ((SELECT Max(Apps2.ContactID)
FROM ABI_RiO.dbo.vwSGReferrals Refs2
LEFT JOIN ABI_RiO.dbo.vwSGAppointmentsPD Apps2 ON Refs2.ClientID = Apps2. ClientID AND Refs2.ReferralNumber = Apps2.ReferralNumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN ABI_RiO.SchemaSG.AmsOutcome AS AOUT ON AOUT.Code=APPs2.Outcome
WHERE Refs2.ClientID = Refs.ClientID
AND Refs2.ReferralNumber = Refs.ReferralNumber
AND NationalCode=5))))
GROUP BY GP.Code, Refs.SpecialtyReferredTo
ORDER BY GP.Code
```

This means my problem lies in the last part of the query here:

```
 (SELECT Max(Apps2.ContactID)
FROM ABI_RiO.dbo.vwSGReferrals Refs2
LEFT JOIN ABI_RiO.dbo.vwSGAppointmentsPD Apps2 ON Refs2.ClientID = Apps2. ClientID AND Refs2.ReferralNumber = Apps2.ReferralNumber
WHERE Refs2.ClientID = Refs.ClientID
AND Refs2.ReferralNumber = Refs.ReferralNumber
))) OR Apps.ContactID IS NULL)
--GROUP BY GP.Code, Refs.SpecialtyReferredTo
--ORDER BY GP.Code
```

Adding this last query block back in results in an expansion of about 10% in the data eventually output.

Can anyone help me re-write this query and explain why the last part is causing such a degradation in execution performance.
Cheers.

R

Answer (score 0):

My first inclination here would be to change that correlated sub-query in your ISNULL section into two OUTER APPLY calculations that get those values.

```
    SELECT
DISTINCT    Refs.SpecialtyReferredTo
    FROM    ABI_RiO.dbo.vwSGReferrals Refs
    LEFT JOIN ABI_RiO.dbo.vwSGAppointmentsPD Apps
    ON      Refs.ClientID = Apps.ClientID
            AND Refs.ReferralNumber = Apps.ReferralNumber
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ABI_RiO.SchemaSG.AmsOutcome AS AOUT
    ON      AOUT.Code = APPs.Outcome
    LEFT JOIN ABI_RiO.SchemaSG.ClientIndex CI
    ON      Refs.ClientID = CI.ClientID
    LEFT JOIN ABI_RiO.SchemaSG.GenGPPractice GP
    ON      GP.Code = CI.AIMTCCurrentGPPractice
OUTER APPLY (select max(Apps2.ContactID) as ContactID1 ...) as OuterApply1
OUTER APPLY (select max(Apps2.ContactID) as ContactID2 ...) as OuterApply2
    WHERE   Refs.DischargeReason IS NULL
AND (Apps.ContactID = ISNULL(ContactID1, ContactID2) or Apps.ContactID IS NULL )
```

That correlated sub-query will, generally speaking, result in performance issues as you're trying to calculate that for each and every row. Switching those calculations to an OUTER APPLY will at least let you work on those as a set.

There are some examples of OUTER APPLY here: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/
and here: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-apply-basics/

Comment: Thanks Peter - I'm unfamiliar with that methodology. I'll read the articles before I progress.

Comment: Hi Peter - I decided to completely deconstruct the query before applying the above solutions (this was written by an ex-colleague on a database I'm not familiar with). On doing so, I notice that the outer select actually retrieves the exact same values as the correlated sub-query PLUS Outer select and the outer select achieves my purpose on it's own in about a second, so I'm going to stick with that. I have looked at the articles you suggested though and I've learnt a fair bit I wasn't aware of before, so cheers for that. R.